# Initilize COM Object on Python Rpyc Server and re-use it?

Tags: python, win32com, rpyc

I am using rpyc python server to process requests sent by email. I am loading them into an Excel blotter and the idea is to auto-update the excel by running a macro once a new request is received.

However, I cannot initialize a workbook object. The below code works ok to open the workbook (startExcel) but then when I run the RunThis method it prints 0 as in the workbook has not been initialized.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import rpyc
from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
import pythoncom
import os
import time


class MyService(rpyc.Service):

    excelInitialized = False
    xl = 0
    wb = 0

    def exposed_startExcel(self):

        pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        xl, wb = loadExcelEnv()
        print wb
        ws = wb.Sheets('RequestBlotter')
        xl.Application.Run("ThisWorkbook.cleardata")
        xl.Application.Run("ThisWorkbook.UpdateBlotter")

    def exposed_RunThis(self):
        print self.wb


def loadExcelEnv():

    xl = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    xl.Visible = True

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(dir_path + '\\Repo Blotter.xlsm')

    return xl, wb

server = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 33445, protocol_config = {"allow_public_attrs" : True})
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


t = Thread(target = server.start)
t.daemon = True

t.start()

conn = rpyc.connect("localhost", 33445)
c = conn.root
c.startExcel()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    c.exposed_RunThis()
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `c.exposed_startExcel` where you have `c.startExcel`?

Answer (score 0):

In `MyService.exposed_startExcel`, the scope of the variable `wb` is the method; you are never setting the attribute `MyService.wb`. To do so, set `self.wb` instead of `wb`.